# Is there a way I can view suggested edits to a post with reputation lower than 2K?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I got an email saying that there had been activity on one of my posts. The 
link given was https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9742238

When I click the Next button on that page, for more information, this message is displayed:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.

I'm taking that to mean that I need a reputation of at least 2K to view the details of the suggested edits - is that correct?

Or am I misunderstand the message and it is occurring because there are no more suggested edits to view? That is, is it a bug in the forum software?

If there is more information available, is there a way I can access with a reputation less than 2K?  If so that seems useless to me because I cannot view it.  And why would a higher reputation be needed to view more information?

I can understand needing higher reputation to make such suggestions or Approve or Reject a posting, but why do you need a higher reputation to view the more information?

However, as I said I may be misinterpreting the error message and or the purpose of the Next button.

---

Now I'm really confused. I found the way to review "inbox messages" and one of them pointed me to a page showing suggested edits to one of my questions. It is at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9521345

I don't understand why some things are marked through on the left side but shown exactly the same way on the left side. That is, there are items which have red backgrounds on the left which are identical (letter for letter) to items in the right side which have green backgrounds.

What am I not understanding about "suggested edits" and the display there of?

Comment: You gotta be logged in to review edits on your own questions, but AFAIK that is the only requirement.

Comment: Clicking on the Next button takes you to the next edit but you can only review your own edit if you have less than 2000 rep so unless you had suggested edits on two of your questions and they happened to be sequential (only likely if yours are the only 2 suggested edits in the system which would be a very quiet day for Stack Overflow) then the Next button isn't really useful for you.

Comment: @RobertLongson: The queue will attempt to give you any items it can, so there's no sequential requirement. It's still quite rare to have two suggestions to review at any one time, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR

You should not be able to <strike>see any details of</strike><sup>1</sup> review any suggested edits until you earn the [edit anywhere privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).  The one exception is that as the owner of the post, you always have a binding vote for approving or rejecting a suggested edit on your own posts.

---

> When I click the Next button on that page, for more information, this message is displayed:

That's part of the workflow for 2k users to continue reviewing other pending suggested edits.  Since you don't have the reputation for that privilege, this part of the dialog is really irrelevant to you.  That's a bit confusing, and maybe should be changed.

> I can understand needed higher reputation to make such suggestions or Approve or Reject a posting but why do you need a higher reputation to view the more information?

With the exception of suggestions to your post, you'll never see any details of other pending suggested edits until you get the [2k edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).  So no, there is no more information that you will be able to see because that information is not really useful to you.  If approved, you'll see the newest revision like everyone else.  If rejected, the reviewers have spared you from wasting your time looking at a sub-par suggestion.

You won't even be able to see other pending suggestions on posts you don't own.<sup>1</sup>  This has the side effect of not allowing concurrent pending suggestions on the same post from <2k users.

> I don't understand why some things are marked through on the left side but shown exactly the same way on the left side. That is, there are items which have red backgrounds on the left which are identical (letter for letter) to items in the right side which have green backgrounds.

That's usually due to formatting changes.  If you really want the details, you can look at the markdown tab of the review to see the pre-rendered markdown.  Markdown is pretty powerful and lets you apply a lot of formatting.  In this specific case, the suggestion used backticks (`) to apply `inline code formatting` to a few keywords in your post.

---

Notes/corrections:

<sup>1</sup>As [Kendra points out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307535/is-there-a-way-i-can-view-suggested-edits-to-a-post-with-reputation-lower-than-2/307538?noredirect=1#comment258378_307538), if you are still <2k reputation, you *can see the details* of suggestions, but you'll be unable to actually review the suggestions.  If you have a direct link to the suggestion, (or if you do some url manipulation) you'll be able to see the actual suggestion, but that's largely extraneous information since you can't act on it.

Comment: _"You should not be able to see any details of any suggested edits until you earn the edit anywhere privilege."_ Actually, if linked to the review, a <2k user can see the edit and the current votes on it. We just can't get to any reviews without a direct link, and we get the note we need 2k rep to review the edit. Just as a small note.

Comment: @Kendra my mistake, I've added some corrections the answer.